# IIS URL redirection after the url redirection (used exact match) it shows same from URL only

Tags: wordpress, iis, url-rewriting

IIS URL redirection after the url redirection (used exact match) it shows same from URL only. like this (faq/general-information/can-i-check-the-status-of-my-orders/?lang=zh-hans). I want redirect this url

From url: localhost:96/faq/general-information/can-i-check-the-status-of-my-orders/?lang=zh-hans

To url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

After the redirection I am getting this url localhost:96/faq/general-information/can-i-check-the-status-of-my-orders/?lang=zh-hans. I don't know why. What happened?

Comment: From your description, I can't understand your requirement clearly. Do you want to redirect `localhost:96/faq/general-information/can-i-check-the-status-of-my-orders/?lang=zh-hans` to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`? Can you provide the rewrite rule you created?

Comment: <rule name="GMDRedirect29" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="/faq/general-information/can-i-check-the-status-of-my-orders/?lang=zh-hans" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?" />
                </rule>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, I think you want to create a redirect rule that will `localhost:96/faq/general-information/can-i-check-the-status-of-my-orders/?lang=zh-hans` redirect to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

Please try using the following rule：

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="GMDRedirect29" stopProcessing="true">
         <match url="faq/general-information/can-i-check-the-status-of-my-orders" />
         <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="lang=zh-hans" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Redirect" url="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: thanks for response. I tried this, it shows 404  source error. ( purpose : after the page content removed we need to use that url)